# Identifying and Replacing French Characters in Excel for Email Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, mail-merge

How do I identify the character é in a value and replace it with e?

I am using Excel to hold data for a MailMerge. Each column represents a piece of data that is either used in the MailMerge or uploaded onto a CRM.

In the case of French names there are often characters like é in a last name, for example: Bélanger. It would be correct to address someone by "Ms. Bélanger" but "jenny.bélanger@url.com" is not allowed.

For the sake of this question assume that columns A, B, C are First, Last, Email respectively.

A and B are entered in manually. Column C contains an email that is generated using concatenate and following the company email naming convention.For example if email naming convention is "first.last@url.com" the formula is =concatenate(lower(a1),"."lower(b1),"@url.com")

Is it possible to enter a French name correctly as a value in the name column but automatically replace an é with e for the email value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to wrap your output in a series of `SUBSTITUTE` functions, for example

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        CONCATENATE( LOWER(A1), ".", LOWER(B1), "@url.com" ),
    "á", "a"),
"é", "e")
```

for all the letters that you might need to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Open the VBA macro editor and insert this code in a module:

```
Public Function DeFrenchify(s As String) As String

    s = VBA.Replace(s, "é", "e")
    s = VBA.Replace(s, "ç", "c")
    s = VBA.Replace(s, "è", "e")
    '...add more replacements here for all characters...

    DeFrenchify= s
End Function
```

Then on your worksheet, if your original names are on cell A1, for example, just use

`=DeFrenchify(A1)`

in formulas to get what you want.

You need to have macros enabled for this to work; and be advised that this is not very good in terms of performance, but you shouldn't worry unless you have thousands of names and they change a lot. But if your spreadsheet starts to feel slow after this, get a better solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for providing this. I took the easy way out by using the other response but I'm looking forward to trying this out when I have to DeFrenchify more than 100 names